# Out of memory when uploading large files to S3 using AWS SDK for Java 2.x

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've got a Java 11 Coretto lambda function where I download files from S3, zip them and upload the zip file to another S3 bucket. This works well with AWS SDK 1.X using [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html), but I'm trying not to mix V1 and V2 AWS JAVA SDKs in my project to keep it clean and to minimize the dependencies.

When using the V2 S3Client (*software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3*) and doing a *putObject* of a large zip file, I get an OutOfMemory error even though I'm providing an InputStream and setting the *contentLength*, which I thought would be enough to prevent the whole zip file from being loaded into memory before upload could begin.

Here's my code that causes an OutOfMemory error when trying to upload a large zip file (several gigs):

```java
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile);

PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(zipBucket)
        .key(zipFile.getName())
        .contentType("application/zip")
        .contentLength(zipFile.length())
        .expires(expiration.toInstant()).build();

s3Client.putObject(request, RequestBody.fromInputStream(targetStream, zipFile.length()));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `RequestBody.fromInputStream` you are right, this piece if code loads the whole payload to the RAM. Maybe there is a way passing the stream directly or a file reference ?

Comment: I tried RequestBody.fromFile() , but still got OutOfMemory

Comment: For huge files I suggest to use MultiPartUpoload API. See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Comment: Thanks, @Samuel, but I'm trying not to use the v1 SDK (AmazonS3). It seems the documentation for v2 (S3Client) is lacking, but I found some example code in the official AWS github repo that might help: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/services/s3/src/it/java/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/UploadMultiplePartTestBase.java

Comment: I also use fromInputStream,but I don't meet OutOfMemory error(I upload 1GB mp4 file,with java memory add about 100MB).Any futher update?

Comment: @mengzz: Nope, still using TransferManager from Java AWS SDK V1 along with my otherwise V2 based project

Comment: Thanks, the hint with MultipartUpload saved me! Some examples (not the most relevant cases though) can be found under: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3

Comment: @MJey, so AWS SDK V2 has a MultiPartUpload API now?

Comment: @Lerdal Yes, what you need is `s3.createMultipartUpload`, `s3.uploadPart` and `s3.completeMultipartUpload`

Comment: Thanks @MJey. I was able to get it to work. Then I discovered that TransferManager is actually now available in Preview: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html. Might switch over to it when it's production ready.

Comment: is transferManger faster than s3Client.putObject?